# import data transfer from mysql to hadoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, bigdata

I installed hadoop 2.7.1 and sqoop 1.4.6 in my system. I am trying to import a table from MySQL to hdfs. I am getting following error:

> at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 17,7175 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!

in this case What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.maybe be useful for you ;)

mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>bd01.19888</value>
</property>
```